# Lotus notes mail client

Tags: 14.04, ibm-lotus-notes

I am finding it difficult to manage webmails.
May I know the stable Lotus-notes web client for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Notes web client run on Domino server and can work (only) with Domino mails. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I need to run this on my personal laptop of ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No, that's what you think you can do and want. What exactly are your trying to achieve? Please read again the previous comment.

Comment: Most Ubuntu flavors come with Thunderbird as email client. Other can be installed if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is mistaken. The Lotus Notes web client needs to be installed on the *server* side by your e-mail provider so you can use it in any modern web browser on the *client* side. There's nothing you can do about that as an end-user (except to ask your e-mail provider to set up Lotus Domino on their end).

However, there are multiple mail user agents ready for installation in Ubuntu's package repositories. See for instance the following questions:

- [What E-mail clients are available?](/q/47723/175814)
- [Mail program for Netbook](/q/48268/175814)